# Visual Studio 2010 and SSE 4.2

Tags: c++, sse2

I would like to know, what is necessary to set in Visual Studio 2010, to have SSE 4.2 enabled? I would like to use it because of optimized POPCNT...

How can I test, if all settings are ok?

thanks

---

well, I tried to use your solution, however `<nmmintric.h>` is not included in vstudio2010 and standard `__popcnt` requires `int` instead of `std::bitset<>` :(

any idea?

---

Thx for the hint with the correct header. However, it seems that: `error C3861: '_mm_popcnt_u64': identifier not found`, I found only `_mm_popcnt_u32`, however I don't know, how to use it with `bitset`, or should I use just `bitset<>.count`? It can't work without anz settings of compiler, can it?

nobody knows ?

Comment: You'll have to use the intrinsic, _mm_popcnt_u64, header file `<nmmintric.h>`.

Comment: just include this header? nothing more?

Comment: Erm, no, you actually have to write _mm_popcnt_u64 in your code.  Also better check it the cpu you run on supports the instruction.

Comment: so instead of bitset<>.count() use _mm_popcnt_u64, right? And is it necesarry to set anything in project settings?

Comment: Yes, no.  Test it on some old XP machines and let us know how that turned out.

Comment: well, I don`t have any xp machine... is there any chance, how can I test if it is working? or just measure the speed and compare it?

Comment: I don't have an XP machine either.  Only your customers do.

Comment: is there any chance, how can I test if it is working? or just measure the speed and compare it?

Comment: Have you considered trying it?  We better quit, the machine is starting to get angry at me.

Comment: well, I tried to use your solution, however `<nmmintric.h>` is not included in vstudio2010 and standard `__popcnt` requires `int` instead of `std::bitset<>` :(

any idea?

Comment: Note the [_mm_popcnt_u64 documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531475.aspx) says the header file is called `nmmintrin.h`

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to test if the _mm_popcnt_u64 intrinsic is working. If you run your code on a system that supports the popcnt instruction then the popcnt instruction will work.  If you run your code on a system that doesn't support popcnt then you'll get something like an illegal instruction exception (0xC000001D).  As @Hans already said: you need to check the cpu supports popcnt - by using [__cpuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh(v=VS.100).aspx) for example.

Comment: Thx for the hint with the correct header. However, it seems `that: "error C3861: '_mm_popcnt_u64': identifier not found`

Comment: Use `bitset::to_ulong`, how can you be surprised a C API doesn't take a C++ object?  Also consider MIT HAKMEM 169.

Answer (score 7):

you have to write _mm_popcnt_u64 in your code. Also better check it the cpu you run on supports the instruction. 
And build for x64.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <nmmintrin.h>

 int main ()
 {
      unsigned __int64 a = 0x123456789ABCDEF0;

      int res = _mm_popcnt_u64(a);

      printf_s("Result res should be 32: %d\n", res);
      return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

MSDN example for `__popcnt`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385231.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special required for this to work.

You may use intrinsics *mm** and include the appropriate header file, and it will compile if your system support the given features.

The compiler does not inspect or touch inline assembly, so whatever you put in there will go through the build, although your application will crash if your system does not support an instruction.

Other than that, the VS2010 optimizer only targets SSE2.